# Unexpected behavior in JWT authentication using cookies

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jwt, passport.js, passport-local

I am learning Node.js and making my first project. I am using JWT for user authentication on the project. I am using cookies to send JWT and on the server-side I am able to extract the cookie and correctly obtain the expected payload. However I am facing an unexpected behavior as in the authentication function I am always getting signed up by one particular user.

login route:

```
usersRouter.route('/login')
.post(passport.authenticate('local'), (req,res) => {
  console.log('Generating token for: ', req.user._id);
  var token = authenticate.getToken({_id: req.user._id});

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.cookie('jwt', token, {signed: true});
  res.redirect('/');
  
})
```

authentication code:

```
exports.getToken = function(user){
    return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey, {
        expiresIn: 3600
    });
};

var extractFromCookie = function (req)
{   
    var token = null;
    if(req && req.signedCookies)
        token = req.signedCookies.jwt;
    return token;
}

var opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = extractFromCookie;
opts.secretOrKey = config.secretKey;

exports.jwtPassport = passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    console.log("Jwt Payload: ", jwt_payload);

    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, (err,user) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err,false);
        }
        else if(user){
            console.log('Found user is: ', user);
            return done(null, user);
        }
        else
            return done(null,false);
    });
}));


exports.verifyUser = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false});
```

Printing in the console

```
Jwt Payload:  { _id: '5f49430180e4092eac7962be', iat: 1599066593, exp: 1599070193 }
Found user is: 
{
  _id: 5f4904d106efe130084808a4,
   .
   .
   . other details
   .
}
```

How is the search resulting in a user with different id? I am not able to figure out why is this happening. Please help!

**Edit:** getToken is a function to generate token from the id of the user sent from login router.

Comment: What's `authenticate.getToken`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla getToken is a function to generate token using the id of the user. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally access to undefined property `sub` in `jwt_payload` so you actually send `undefined` as value to the `findOne` function.

This should work.

```
User.findById(jwt_payload._id, (err,user) => {
```

Comment: I had tried doing that, but User.findOne function is not even executed then. It just sends user unauthorized.

Comment: does `findOne` callback get called? what are the values of `err`/`user`?

Comment: findOne callback was getting called, but with an error (status 401) since it wasn't able to find 'id' field.

Answer (score 0):

It was just some small mistakes after all.

The only thing that was needed to be changed is as follows:
`User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, (err,user) =>`

As @Michael pointed out, there's no field name sub in jwt_payload, we need to put _id instead. Also, in the User schema, it's _id field and not id field.

Made these changes, and viola!

Comment: I edited my answer, I think this is the correct answer :)